# Rails form show extra button on iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

This shows all the comments but it also shows an extra edit and delete button at the end. But when I reverse the order that is, I show Add comment after all the comments this bug seems to disappear. Anyone can point out what is happening? Also, I would like suggestions for better coding standards.

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
<h3>Add Comment</h3>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, size:80 %>
<%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>

<h3>Comments</h3>

<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <h4><%= comment.name %></h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', [comment.article, comment], method: :put, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
            <td><%= button_to 'Delete', [comment.article, comment], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As per your code,the behaviour is correct. What you want it do?

Comment: Why does it show an extra edit and delete button after all the comments have been displayed?

Comment: Since you have them in the code,it shows :)

Comment: It shows both the buttons along with each comment. That's fine. And then after all comments have been displayed, it outputs an extra edit and delete button. Why?

Comment: You get the same result?

Comment: yes.. an extra pair of buttons.

Comment: Can you update your post with the screenshot please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tweak your code like this

```
<table>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <tr>
      <td><h4><%= comment.name %></h4></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', [comment.article, comment], method: :put, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.article, comment], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>
    </tr>
</div>
<% end %>

</table>
```

Also use `link_to` not `button_to`.